# How can we frame ES query for select from a group of ids

Tags: sql, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Here is the SQL query I am looking to write in ES

```
    select * 
    from es
    where sale_id in (select * from ES group by sale_id)
```

I have done a group by of the query as follows:

```
    {
      "size": 200,
      "aggs": {
        "group_by_state": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "sale.sale_id",
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

### Explanation

This code is used to group by sale ids. How can I get all the documents associated with those sale ids?

There can be many sale ids in the group, right now I have 10.